# Enumerate Dictionary Within ASP.NET Web Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, import, enumerate

I have a ASP.NET (C#) web page in which I want to enumerate a dictionary in a code render block:

```
<% foreach (Dictionary<string, string> record in parsedData) { %>
     <div>...Some HTML Code...</div>
<% } %>
```

But I get an error like:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The
>   type or namespace name 'Dictionary'
>   could not be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

How do I import System.Collections.Generic into the page itself? Here is my page directive:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MyCSharpClass.aspx.cs" Inherits="_MyCSharpClass" %>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this a number of ways.

In your web.config you can add `System.Collections.Generic` to the namespaces element.

You can also reference it directly as `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>`

You should also be able to do it on the page directly (though I must admit I haven't tested this way):

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Collections.Generic" %>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add an [`import`](http://www.aspdotnetcodes.com/Asp.Net_Page_Directives.aspx) page directive near the top of your .aspx page.

**E.g.,**

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Collections.Generic"%>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this to the top of the *.aspx page

`<%@ Import Namespace="System.Collections.Generic" %>`